# How do I replace newlines only between numbers and a sentence?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, newline, digits

I want to remove newlines in some special cases. I have this text:

```
0 
15.239 
23.917 
 Reprenem el debat que avui els oferim entorn de les perspectives d'aquest dos mil set. &lt;ehh&gt; Estavem parlant concretament dels temes 
30.027 
de la seguretat mundial 
 una miqueta 
de la intervencio
33.519 
que
```

And I want to replace newlines between a number and some text as so:

```
0 
15.239 
23.917 Reprenem el debat que avui els oferim entorn de les perspectives d'aquest dos mil set. &lt;ehh&gt; Estavem parlant concretament dels temes 
30.027 de la seguretat mundial una miqueta de la intervencio
33.519 que
```

I want only to erase the new lines between numbers and a sentence.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is there is a double quotes present at the start?

Comment: no is not @AvinashRaj

Comment: Catalan subtitles? : )

Comment: something similar @fedorqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk`:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{printf "\n"}{printf $0}' filename
```

For handling `DOS` line breaks:

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{printf "\n"}{printf $0}' filename
```

Demo:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{printf "\n"}{printf $0}' filename                        

0 
15.239 
23.917  Reprenem el debat que avui els oferim entorn de les perspectives d'aquest dos mil set. &lt;ehh&gt; Estavem parlant concretament dels temes 
30.027 de la seguretat mundial  una miqueta de la intervencio
33.519 que que
```

Explained code:

- `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` : Delete `DOS` linebreaks.
- `/^[0-9\.]+/{printf "\n"}`: When the line begins with a `number`/`dot` combination, print just a carriage return an continue with record processing.
- `{printf $0}` : For the remain record or the ones not started by numbers just prints `$0` without line breaks.
- At the end , placing the carriage return just before the numbers and ignoring the rest makes the trick.

Comment: I'm sure that the OP (and any subsequent viewers of this question) would appreciate some explanation.

Comment: Thanks @klashxx but it does not work, I have the same output as before

Comment: This is my output using vi,( I don not understand why I get newlines while you don't):
0 ^M15.239 ^M23.917 ^M Reprenem el debat que avui els oferim entorn de les perspectives d'aquest dos mil set. &lt;ehh&gt; Estàvem parlant concretament dels temes ^M30.027 ^Mde la seguretat mundial ^M una miqueta ^Mde la intervenció ^M33.519 ^Mque ^Mque

Comment: @Sergi you have a DOS encoding and it is breaking everything. You need to clean it by running `dos2unix`.

Comment: klashxx, note `printf $0` can also be written as `print ""`.

Comment: I have updatep my answer for ``DOS`` linebreaks @Sergi

Comment: Hi again @klashxx . Regarding the question of the past 2 days, is it possible to solve this little issue?
9.545 hello
.
10.544 bye

I want that dot goes up and not create a new line, I'm struggling with "awk" but it's impossible for me right now

Answer (score 2):

I'll go by your example output, which also erases newlines in the middle of a sentence. You can use this:

```
sed ':a $!{N;ba}; s/\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' filename
```

That is

```
:a $!{N;ba}          # assemble the whole file in the pattern space
s/\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g  # remove newlines that are not directly before a number
```

To handle DOS linebreaks, you can use

```
#                   vvvv-- new stuff here
sed ':a $!{N;ba}; s/\r\?\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' filename
```

that will optionally match a `\r` before a `\n` and remove the whole `\r\n` in case it finds a DOS linebreak.

Or you can use dos2unix.

Comment: Thank you @Wintermute but still can't remove the new lines

Comment: Equivalent in awk `awk -vRS= '$0=gensub("\n([^0-9])","\\1","g")' filename`

Comment: @JID in GNU awk, that is.

Comment: @Sergi: Can you elaborate? It works for me with your sample. What is wrong with the output you get?

Comment: I obtain the same output before to apply your new command, everything separated by a newline

Comment: I cannot reproduce that; I get the changed file printed to stdout. Do you mean that the file itself doesn't change? If you want to change it in place, use `sed -i` (or better `sed -i.bak` to have a backup in case you don't like the result).

Comment: on my aix (posix version) i need to add several newline instead of space and `;`for working, maybe the similar problem if not in GNU sed `sed ':a^J$!{N;ba^J}^Js/\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' YourFile` (where ^J are real new line)

Comment: @Wintermute note the OP mentions some "^M" problems in the other answer. That must be why your solution doesn't work to him. It does to me and I like the explanation, so +1!

Comment: I fixed my problem, thanks to @fedorqui . I had a format problem and "dos2unix" helped me a lot

Comment: Oh, DOS linebreaks. I'll add something for that.